# How to make a node.js webscraper periodically check an endpoint for data updates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, web-scraping, emit

I am writing a discord bot which aggregates data from an third-party API.

There is a design pattern from `discord.js` which I want to follow for my web-scraping functions, wherein one instantiates a client object, and performs actions when the client emits specific events, [like so:](https://discord.js.org/#/)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

To my understanding this code will run indefinitely, performing actions each time a specific event is emitted, e.g. `ready` or `message`.

I cannot find out how such functionality is implemented. More specifically, I can't figure out how the discord `client` object continually looks for changes, and emits an event when it notices them.

The reason I want to emulate this design pattern is so that I can run one node.js application which will, say every 10 minutes, reach out to the API and see if there is new information, and log it into a database when there are changes.

My initial thought is something along these lines, but it blows up the callstack with an out of memory error.

```
const events = require("events");

class ScrapeEmitter extends events.EventEmitter {}
const scrapeEmitter = new ScrapeEmitter();

scrapeEmitter.on("timeExpired", () => console.log("call scraping code here"));

while (true) {
  setTimeout(() => scrapeEmitter.emit("timeExpired"), 1500);
}
```

The end goal is to, from `index.js`, write the following, and have it both listen for discord events, while also scraping for data.

```
import * as scraper from "./core/scraper";
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
scraper.begin_scraping();
```

Comment: you can probably use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and leave the `while` loop.

Comment: I think that's exactly how it should work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of code

```
while (true) {
  setTimeout(() => scrapeEmitter.emit("timeExpired"), 1500);
}
```

creates an infinite amount of timeouts. What you need to do is **only start a timeout after the previous one has completed**. An example is:

```
function loop() {
setTimeout(loop, 1500);
}
```

This calls the function after 1500 seconds, which in turn calls the function after 1500 seconds, and so on.

**However, the better solution is to use `setInterval()`**. It looks like this:

```
function loop() {};
setInterval(loop, 1500);
```

So, instead of writing

```
while (true) {
  setTimeout(() => scrapeEmitter.emit("timeExpired"), 1500);
}
```

Write

```
setInterval(() => scrapeEmitter.emit("timeExpired"), 1500);
```

This removes the infinite loop and acts as expected.

*I'm just translating @Worthy Alpaca's answer into a comment. It's a community wiki, so I get no reputation*